# Converting float32 to int32

Tags: go

I am seeing some strange behavior converting float32 to int32:

```
var f float32 = math.MaxInt32

fmt.Printf("%d %0.1f %d\n", math.MaxInt32, f, int32(f))
```

prints

```
2147483647 2147483648.0 -2147483648
```

(At Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/SI0RtpZFkwa)

My guess is that there are a few things going on here, like general IEEE floating point imprecision and untamed automatic conversions. I would almost expect the "off by one" type of error, but why the sign conversion?

Seems like a bug, but at the very least, it's surprising. This cropped up in a larger system that started behaving strangely at the edges.

Ultimately, I just want to be able to convert `float32` values to `int32` in some reasonable way.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a combination of insufficient precision and int overflow (causing the sign change).

Comment: You can see that the conversion to `float32` has made `f` larger than `MaxInt32`, what else would you expect? You also said you expect to see it off by one, and `MaxInt32 + 1` rolls over to `-2147483648`

Comment: `MaxFloat32 > MaxInt32` and`MinFloat32 < MinInt32` and `int32 != NaN` and so on. See [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Comment: @JimB I would expect an overflow error

Comment: From the first rule of numeric conversions: " The conversion always yields a valid value; there is no indication of overflow"

Comment: I see. So to do a rational conversion from float32 to int32 requires several lines of boundary condition checks and whatnot. Got it.